# How do I make an ActionBar with a background like the YouTube app

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm working on an Android application, and I decided that I really like the style of the ActionBar of the YouTube app, the Google I/O 2012 app, and the Play Store.  It has a grey background with repeating diagonal lines.  [Here is a picture of it.](http://developer.android.com/design/media/action_bar_pattern_overview.png)  Does anyone know how to do this?  I know how to make different colors but I don't know how to style it like this.

Comment: Use a shape with repeating bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look this site : http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Look inside the lib, in the demos have one tab (Styled) that do exactly what you want.

:D

Answer (score 4):

Set this pattern to the background of your ActionBar:

```
getActionBar().actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pattern_dark_xml));
```

Your pattern_dark_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <bitmap
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:src="@drawable/pattern_dark"
         android:tileMode="repeat" />
</layer-list>
```

And here is a example of a pattern:
[image: dark pattern]

Comment: Is there a way to do this soley in XML so that I wouldn't have to put that in every activity?

Comment: Also, this doesn't work because setBackgroundDrawable won't take ints (R values).  At least it won't work for me...

Comment: You open two braces and close three.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.action_bar_bg));
```