# Change ActionBarSherlock background color AFTER it has been shown

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to change the action bar's background ([ABS](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) 4.2) when I navigate from page 1 to 2 of a `ViewPager`.

I've tried `setTheme(R.style...)` but as it says on the docs it should be called before the view is drawn. In fact I'm getting no changes at all.

I've created the theme using [this](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) and I want to switch between the solid and the transparent action bar style.

On the `setTheme(int)` I'm not using the `int` of the style, I've created a new theme that overrides only the `android:actionBarStyle` and `actionBarStyle` with the transparent drawable.

Is there a way to change the color on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your background as a drawable xml (or it can be a color if you want a simple color). And then use `setBackgroundDrawable(drawable)` method.

Look here: [How do I make an ActionBar with a background like the YouTube app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409081/how-do-i-make-an-actionbar-with-a-background-like-the-youtube-app)

and here: [ActionBar setBackgroundDrawable() nulling background from Thread/Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002691/actionbar-setbackgrounddrawable-nulling-background-from-thread-handler)

Comment: Thank you, I was following Jake Wharton advices on other answers and those didn't help!